# Is it possible to define variables based on the assembly output (.dll or .exe) in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to define variables based on the assembly output?

Something like this:

```
   if (assembly is .exe)
{
   Path = "this/path"
}
  else if (assembly is .dll) 
{
   Path = "this/path"
}
```

I need a different path for a variable based on the assembly, as I sometimes run my program as .exe, and other times I build it as .dll and run it in another program/PC.

Comment: This sort of things are usually achieved in C/C++ via carefully placed preprocessor defines.

Comment: Are you trying to detect if the running code is an *executable* or `dll`?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you look for a variable that would tell you whether this translation unit compiles as a part of an exe or a dll? In msvc you can use a macro _DLL

Comment: @Galik yes I am

Comment: @Igor R, I would like to define the variable based on if it is dll or exe. I need a different path for a variable based on the assembly, as I sometimes run my program as .exe, and other times I build as .dll  and run it in another program

Comment: The main difference between a DLL and an EXE is that the EXE has a `main()`... think about that for a moment, and work from there. Hint: Don't try to use tools for things they are not meant for. ;-)

Comment: You can set a macro with your compile command (-D on GCC), you could set it differently if you are compiling dll or exe?

Comment: "[...] and run it in another program/PC." ... smells like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is that path actually? Why does it need to be different? You should find a solution that works independent of whether the code is in an executable or dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @oakad 's hint with preprocessor defines and some googling:

```
#ifdef _WINDLL
    Path = "this/path";
#else 
    Path = "other/path";
#endif
```